# Power Fx syntax

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps-canvas

I'm new to Power Fx and trying to learn syntax. I've spent a few hours so far plugging and playing but not sure if I'm thinking correctly. Originally Sharepoint displayed whoever the anniversary was for the current day. Simple but i was asked by HR to Try to update SharePoint so that if it's a Friday and we have an anniversary on Saturday it displays on Friday and if We have an anniversary on Sunday it displays on a Monday. Here is my current code

This is to check how many records exist:

```
If(
    CountRows(
        Filter(
            'Employee Anniversaries', //Check to see how many records are available
            (Month(Now()) = Month(DateValue('Anniversary Date')) && Day(Now()) = Day(DateValue('Anniversary Date'))) ||
            (Weekday(Now()) = 5 && Month(Now()) = Month(DateValue('Anniversary Date')) && Day(Now() + 1) = Day(DateValue('Anniversary Date'))) ||
            (Weekday(Now()) = 3 && Month(Now()) = Month(DateValue('Anniversary Date')) && Day(Now() - 1) = Day(DateValue('Anniversary Date')))
        )
    ) = 0,
```

This checks to see how many records are available for today.

```
Set(
    recordcount,
    CountRows(
        Filter(
            'Employee Anniversaries', // check how many records are available for today
            (Month(Now()) = Month(DateValue('Anniversary Date')) && Day(Now()) = Day(DateValue('Anniversary Date'))) ||
            (Weekday(Now()) = 5 && Month(Now()) = Month(DateValue('Anniversary Date')) && Day(Now() + 1) = Day(DateValue('Anniversary Date'))) ||
            (Weekday(Now()) = 3 && Month(Now()) = Month(DateValue('Anniversary Date')) && Day(Now() - 1) = Day(DateValue('Anniversary Date')))
        )
    )
);
```

Basically my thought was to take and set the logic that if today was Friday then we would set the month as now and make the day today plus one day and pull that Person. The same with if it was a Monday to set the day as today but -1 and pull that person. The thinking I believe is correct but I'm not sure if the syntax is correct. I was pulling the Defaults of Weekday being 1 for Sunday and 7 for a Saturday. The table this is pulling from is just 2 columns about 150 rows. Column 'Name' and 'Anniversary Date' set as MM/DD/YYYY. This obviously doesn't account for a leap year or if the end of the month happens to fall on the weekend. My first step was just to get what I was doing to work first.

I have the most experience with Java and some JS and C but still learning. Every experience is a learning experience.